# Verificar se o array() está vazio com PHP

Tags: php

Tenho um formulário com vários campos. Para pegar os valores, estou fazendo dessa forma (coloquei apenas os 4 primeiros):

```
<?php
  $dados[0] = $_POST["TipoSanguineo"];
  $dados[1] = $_POST["PlanoSaude"];
  $dados[2] = $_POST["CalendarioVacinal"];
  $dados[3] = $_POST["NomeContato"];
  $dados[4] = $_POST["FoneContato"];

  $metodos->cadastrarFichaMedica(array($dados));
?>
```

Para resgatar os valores, faço dessa forma:

```
<?php
...
public function cadastrarFichaMedica($dados){

   for($i = 0; $i < count($dados); $i++){  

       $tipoSanguineo = $dados[$i][0];
       $planoSaude = $dados[$i][1];
       $calendarioVacinal = $dados[$i][2];
       $nomeContato = $dados[$i][3];
       $telefone = $dados[$i][4];
   }
     mysqli_query($this->conexao,"INSERT....");
}
```

Só que os campos do formulário não são obrigatórios e gostaria de saber como faço para que, caso o usuário não preencha nenhum campo, não fazer o cadastro, ou seja, verificar se existem algum campo preenchido. Tentei usar o **count()**, mas mesmo todos os campos estarem vazios, ele sempre me retorna valor 1. Vejam:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(31) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(0) "" [4]=> string(0) "" [5]=> string(0) "" [6]=> string(0) "" [7]=> string(0) "" [8]=> NULL [9]=> NULL [10]=> string(0) "" [11]=> NULL [12]=> NULL [13]=> NULL [14]=> NULL [15]=> NULL [16]=> NULL [17]=> NULL [18]=> NULL [19]=> NULL [20]=> NULL [21]=> NULL [22]=> NULL [23]=> NULL [24]=> NULL [25]=> NULL [26]=> NULL [27]=> NULL [28]=> NULL [29]=> NULL [30]=> NULL } }
```

Comment: Por curiosidade, como está seu HTML? O código que colocou por último está bem esquisito e não parece ser um POST comum. Por acaso seu formulário possui 31 campos? Esquisito que eles vieram como array numérico, inclusive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Muitas coisas não fazem sentido no seu código.

Pelo menos considerando apenas o trecho que postou na pergunta, caberá a você avaliar ao final já que apenas você tem acesso ao resto do projeto.

**Convertendo um array em array...**

```
$dados[0] = $_POST["TipoSanguineo"];
$dados[1] = $_POST["PlanoSaude"];
$dados[2] = $_POST["CalendarioVacinal"];
$dados[3] = $_POST["NomeContato"];
$dados[4] = $_POST["FoneContato"];
```

`$_POST` é uma superglobal do PHP, definida pelo próprio interpretador, do tipo *array* associativo alimentado com os dados que vem através da requisição HTTP. O que você está fazendo aqui é basicamente converter um *array* associativo em outro *array*, só que numérico. Ambos não fazem sentido: criar um outro *array* a partir de um *array* e passar um associativo para um numérico (se por algum motivo você não precisa das chaves, use [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-values.php)).

Você não acha que é muito mais legível fazer `$nome = $dados['nome']` do que `$nome = $dados[0]`?

**Convertendo um array em array... de novo!**

Depois de definir o *array* `$dados` a partir de `$_POST`, você passa-o por parâmetro para `cadastrarFichaMedica`:

```
$metodos->cadastrarFichaMedica(array($dados));
```

Mas, novamente, você criou outro *array* a partir de um *array*, só que agora ainda mais grave: você criou um ***array* de *array***. Se seu `$dado` fosse `['Anderson', 42]`, o método receberá como parâmetro `[['Anderson', 42]]`, o que não faz sentido algum.

Aliás, é por isso que o `count` sempre retorna 1, pois o seu *array* de entrada sempre será um *array* com um valor, que por ventura é um *array*.

**Caminhar pelo array e... não fazer nada?**

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($dados); $i++){  
   $tipoSanguineo = $dados[$i][0];
   $planoSaude = $dados[$i][1];
   $calendarioVacinal = $dados[$i][2];
   $nomeContato = $dados[$i][3];
   $telefone = $dados[$i][4];
}
```

Aqui você está iterando sobre o seu *array*. Como ele é, erroneamente, um *array* de *array*, acessar os valores da forma `$dados[$i][0]` acaba funcionando. A questão aqui é: você está recebendo todos os valores que vieram pela requisição em variáveis distintas e... simplesmente não fez nada com elas.

Você aparentemente executa o `INSERT` fora do laço e isso fará com que seja inserido apenas o último registro iterado. Como seu *array* possui apenas um valor mesmo, isso nem faria diferença e, com sorte, iria produzir o resultado esperado, só que não faz sentido algum.

**Finalmente... o filtro**

Como o [rbz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/330411/5878) respondeu, você pode utilizar a função [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php) para eliminar os valores indesejados. Basicamente o seu código poderia ser algo como:

```
<?php

$dados = array_filter($_POST);
$metodos->cadastrarFichaMedica($dados);
```

Onde o método `cadastrarFichaMedica` seria:

```
public function cadastrarFichaMedica(array $dados){

   $nomeContato = $dados['NomeContato'];
   ...

   mysqli_query($this->conexao,"INSERT....");
}
```

Obviamente que, como você não será capaz de prever quais campos o usuário irá preencher, você deverá verificar a existência de cada um deles.

Comment: "Professor corrige a pergunta e a resposta." +1.

Comment: Olá Anderson. Na verdade o formulário tem mais de 30 campos e confesso que esqueci completamente dessa função nativa, pois trabalho muito pouco com arrays. Obrigado!

Answer (score 9):

Antes de mais nada, cuidado com o `empty`, pois ele pode te enganar dependendo dos valores utilizados.

> Valor Retornado
>
> Retorna FALSE se var existir e não estiver vazia e não conter um valor
>   zerado. Caso contrário retornará TRUE.
>
> O que é visto abaixo é considerado vazio:
>
> "" (uma string vazia)
>
> 0 (0 como um inteiro)
>
> 0.0 (0 como um ponto flutuante)
>
> "0" (0 como uma string)
>
> NULL
>
> FALSE
>
> array() (um array vazio)
>
> $var; (uma variável declarada, mas sem valor)

(documentação: [empty](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php))

---

#### Solução 1

Contando vazios com `array_walk_recursive`:

```
$vazios = 0;
array_walk_recursive($array, function($v,$k) use (&$vazios) {
    if (empty($v)) $vazios++;
});
```

Desta forma, irá contar os vazios, falses, 0, etc.

#### Solução 2

Uma forma de fazer, seria usando `foreach` e `empty` com condição (`if`):

```
$array = array( 0 => 'aa', 1 => 'bbb', 2 => null, 3 => 'ddd', 4 => null);

foreach ($array as $k => $v) {

    if (empty($v)) echo 'vazio';
    else echo 'não vazio';
    echo '<br>';    
}
```

Saída:

```
não vazio
não vazio
vazio
não vazio
vazio
```

#### Veja funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/QOVR3l)

---

#### Solução 3

Como dito pelo [@AndersonCarlosWoss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/330409/verificar-se-o-array-est%C3%A1-vazio-com-php#comment668904_330411), usando `array_filter` e `empty`.

Existem diversas formas, veja 3 exemplos distintos (`$arrayf1`, `$arrayf2`, `$arrayf3`) :

```
$array = array( 0 => 'aa', 1 => 'bbb', 2 => null, 3 => 'ddd', 4 => null);

$arrayf1 = array_filter($array, function($v){if(!empty($v)) return true;});
$arrayf2 = array_filter($array, function($v){return !empty($v);});
$arrayf3 = array_filter($array);
```

Saída dos 3:

```
Array
(
    [0] => aa
    [1] => bbb
    [3] => ddd
)
```

#### Veja funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/QOVR3l)

---

#### Documentação

[empty](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php)

[array_filter](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php)

Answer (score 5):

*Vou deixar esta resposta aqui como complemento á resposta do camarada @rbz.*

O seu `count` retorna verdadeiro porque o seu array tem 31 elementos, apesar de o conteúdo de cada elemento ser um array vazio.

Você pode verificar se uma variavél está vazia de diversas maneiras, porém convêm  definir o que você considera como uma variável vazia.

Veja os possíveis valores de uma variável vazia:

> `false`
>
> `array()` array sem elementos
>
> `0` número inteiro zero
>
> `"0"` string com o número 0
>
> `null`
>
> `""` uma string vazia

A função que abrange o maior leque de possíbilidades é a função`empty`

`empty($variavel)`

Porém pode utilizar outras funções conforme a sua necessidade.
Veja o retorno de cada função:

> `empty` retorna verdadeiro se a variável for `false` `array()` `0`  `"0"` `null`
>
> `is_null` apenas retorna verdadeiro se a variavel for `null`
>
> `isset` retorna verdadeiro se a variável estiver definida, ou seja se não for `null`

---

**Documentação das funções:**

[empty](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php)
[is_null](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-null.php)
[isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: Boooa! O @AndersonCarlosWoss estava me falando sobre isso no chat! +1

Comment: ehehehe Como é raro usar o chat não me apercebi. My bad

Comment: Precisava ver se tem algo sobre diferenças do `empty, is_null, isset`, porque se não tiver, seria uma boa abrir uma pergunta bem elaborada. Daria uma bela documentação no SO.

Comment: Concordo, força nisso :)

Answer (score 4):

Em complemento às soluções apresentadas pelo @rbz, você pode criar um método como sugerido abaixo para verificar seu array de dados e receber um retorno booleano para validar a omissão de dados na submissão.

```
<?php

$dadosCompletos = [
    'nome' => "Usuario",
    'idade' => 99,
    'cidade' => "Sao Paulo",
];

$dadosParciais = [
    'nome' => null,
    'idade' => "",
    'cidade' => "Rio de Janeiro",
];

function possuiCamposVazios(array $arrayCampos): bool {
    $filtro = array_filter($arrayCampos);
    $dif = array_diff($arrayCampos, $filtro);

    return count($dif) === 0 ? false : true;
}
```

Testando:

```
var_dump(possuiCamposVazios($dadosCompletos));
var_dump(possuiCamposVazios($dadosParciais));
```

Saída:

```
bool(false)
bool(true)
```

Como recomendado pelo pessoal, reavalie a forma que você está fazendo a submissão do formulário, utilize as validações no cliente com os [recursos do HMTL5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation) etc. Pode também usar [alguma biblioteca](https://github.com/Respect/Validation) para validar no lado do servidor caso a aplicação fique mais complexa.

Teste o código online em: https://ideone.com/F1K8b4